# Why my first item look like wrong? (see pic)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

My problem is wrong first item. It isn't like others. Some code creates my table. When I scroll down and scroll up first item becomes like other items, but when at first I load my view, it is bad.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tv cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   [tableView setEditing:YES];
    NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tv dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) 
    {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero reuseIdentifier:MyIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    [cell.textLabel setText: [m_pArrayData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[tableView setEditing:YES];
```

Shouldn't be done here. Do it at viewWillAppear or, much better, toggle it with a button.